# how to validate radio[required] via jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, jquery-validate

ı have 10 group of radio. each group have 2 or 3 or more radio it doesnt matter. you need to select at least 1 radio from each group.

when you submit form it must check and return error if any of them(group) left blank.

ı try some code but couldnt solve it. ı wrote this code to find and show error but it find one by one so its submitting form if there is 1 full.

```
 $('#myForm').submit(function () {

     $(".radiogrup").each(function () {
         var sel = $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

         if (sel == null) {
             alert("error msg");
             return false;

         }

     });


 });
```

html:

if you know how to configure required="required" maybe ı can use it.

```
<div class="radiogrup">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radyo" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
          Radyo</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radyo" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
          Radyo</label>
        <br />

        <input name="" type="submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just check atleast one radiobutton in a group? This forces that the user always will have one checked.

Comment: user must fill all question. ı have 10 question and 10x4 option, so ı need 10 answer.

Answer (score 0):

may be this one can help you don't use $.each for this

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {    
var $elems = $(".radiogrup");

        (function fetch(i) {
            if(i >= $elems.length) return;  // no elems left

            var $elem = $elems.eq(i);

            var sel = $($elem).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            if (sel == null) {
                     alert("error msg"); // just don't call fetch again
            }
            else
            {
                 fetch(i + 1); //next one
                 //apply more code here if form validation successfull
            }
        })(0);  // start with first elem
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateRadioButtons() {  //Function for Validating If Radio Button isselected
     var ischecked = false;
    $('.radiogrup').children('radio').each(function () {   //LoopingthroughradioButtons
    // "this" is the current element(radio) in the loop
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          ischecked = true; //Radio Button is Checked
        }
    });
   if (ischecked == true) {
    alert("Validation Passed");
    }
   else {
    alert("Please select a Radio Button");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your JS code this way:

```
$('form').on("submit",function () {
    var valid=true; 
    $(".radiogrup").each(function(){
        var sel=$(this).find("input:radio:checked");
         if(!sel.length){
             valid=false;
         }
    });
    if(!valid){
        alert("error msg"); 
        return false;
    }

});
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/32aew/

Comment: he has 10 group of radio button how this code will work for all groups

Answer (score 0):

This code work for you

//jQuery

```
$(function(){

 $('#myForm').submit(function () {
         if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').val() != "") {
             return true;
         }

alert('error msg')
return false

     });
})
```

//HTML

```
<form id="myForm" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
          radyo
          </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radyo" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
          Radyo</label>
        <br />

        <input name="" type="submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
```