# XPages setting class of radio group (for required validation)

Tags: jquery, validation, xpages

I need to make a Radio Group have class of "required" so I can use the jQuery Validation plugin, I've tried the suggestions are per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191078/how-to-validate-radiorequired-via-jquery)

This is field:

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <legend class="ui-input-text">Compliant?</legend>

                <xp:radioGroup id="CLCompliant"
                    value="#{docAuditCLAnswer.Compliant}">

                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"
                        id="CLCompliantYes">
                    </xp:selectItem>

                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No"
                        id="CLCompliantNo">
                    </xp:selectItem>

                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="N/A" itemValue="NA"
                        id="CLCompliantNA">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                </xp:radioGroup>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I've tried the following as these isn't a styleClass property, but the attribute is ignored/not rendered:

```
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"
                        id="CLCompliantYes">
                        <xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:attr name="class" value="required">
                            </xp:attr>
                        </xp:this.attrs>
                    </xp:selectItem>
```

I've also tried setting when the document is loaded, but can't select by name without hardcoding the view:_id, is there an equivalent to the x$ XSnippet?

```
$('input:radio[name="view:_id1:CLCompliant"]').addClass("required");
```

Comment: Because `xp:radioGroup` isn't treated as a normal html radio input?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "is not a styleClass"? styleClass is the XPages attribute that gets translated into the HTML attribute class. If that is used for styling or other purposes is up to your style sheet. You can type any style name, you are not limited to what is in a style sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gary, add a script block to your XPage (OutputScript) and add:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="#{id:CLCompliant}"]').addClass("required");
    })
```

... or the jQuery equivalent.

Btw.: It is a usual UI Blunder to use radio groups without a default value. They provide the "trap-door" UI pattern user learned to hate: you can select a value, but can't unselect it. So a better user experience would be to either use a different control (Dropdown) or have a default value set.